# Installing a vitual enviroment on Ubuntu Server 18.04.1 - pip package unable to locate

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04

I'm trying to install python/virtual enviroment on Ubuntu Server 18.04.1

```
python --version
```

> I get: not found

```
python3 --version
```

> ```
> I get: `python 3.6.7`
> ```

```
pip3 freeze
```

> I get:  `Pip3 not found but can be installed "apt install
>   python3-pip"`

```
apt install python3-pip
```

> I get: Unable to locate package 'python3-pip'

This is something contradictory: first I get a message how to install `pip`, then reports that `pip` can't be found.

Answer (score 0):

You should go this to install *pip* :

sudo apt-get install python3-pip

Comment: the same result; I didn't expected to work because on new Os is no need to use apt-get, but I tried; I was already using sudo, just didn't added